# Unbound method error in Python

Tags: python

how is it in Python, (sorry for the newbie question), you can do this:

```
import shutil
shutil.move(..)
```

that mean can use the move() method straightaway, but when created my own class
I have to instantiate it first?

```
import myclass
print myclass.mymethod(...)
```

it gives me "unbound method  must be called with myclass instance....

Is there a good document I can read on this unbound and bound method? I just want to use the method without instantiation.
thanks.

So how shall I code if I just want to use it as is. w/o instantiating?

```
def mymethod()  <----- defined here?
class myclass:
   def __init__ ....
   def mymethod(self)....  <----- define here will give me error w/o instantiation
```

Comment: `ascii_uppercase()` is a **function**, not a method.

Comment: Why is `mymethod` a method in the first place? If you wanted to use it directly, why stick it in a class *at all*?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Aren't functions and methods technically the same thing?

Comment: @Haidro: Methods are wrapper objects. They are generated when functions are used as descriptors. Functions are used as descriptors when looked up on an instance or class (in Python 3 only when on an instance; the function descriptor returns itself when there is no instance).

Comment: Methods are functions that are bound to an object instance. You need to instantiate an object before you can call it's methods. Functions can be called without this, because they are not part of an object.

Comment: @Haidro: but that's a lot of detail to swallow, so we talk about any function defined in a class body as methods.

Comment: @MartijnPieters `ascii_uppercase` is the *constant* `'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'`.

Comment: @Bakuriu: hehe, even better. Indeed, the OP took the worst example here. However, the *spirit* was to refer to an attribute in a module that is callable but does not require an instance as first argument.

Comment: Sorry, i changed the example. say using shutil now. the move() function can be used , like shutil.move(). This is just an example

Comment: So all i am asking and having doubt is, the move() function , how is it coded inside the shutil class if I just want to use it without instantiate?

Comment: As for documentation, you are looking for the [classes tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html), the [descriptor howto](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html) and the [datamodel documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html). The latter two are probably more detailed than you expected. Best to remember: Python is **not** Java and you can define code **without classes**.

Comment: @dorothy: `shutil` **is not a class**. It is a module.

Comment: OHHH...now i get it!! In order to group my functions together, I can always group them in a python file, without creating classes. Gosh..so easy. *slap myself*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be under the impression that you *must* put functions in classes.

This is not the case. `shutil` is not a class, it is a *module*. The only classes the `shutil` module defines are exceptions; everything else in the documented API is a top-level function. You can take a look at the [`shutil` sourcecode](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/shutil.py); the `move` function is defined directly in the module source code as:

```
def move(src, dst):
    """Recursively move a file or directory to another location. This is
    similar to the Unix "mv" command.

    If the destination is a directory or a symlink to a directory, the source
    is moved inside the directory. The destination path must not already
    exist.

    If the destination already exists but is not a directory, it may be
    overwritten depending on os.rename() semantics.

    If the destination is on our current filesystem, then rename() is used.
    Otherwise, src is copied to the destination and then removed.
    A lot more could be done here...  A look at a mv.c shows a lot of
    the issues this implementation glosses over.

    """
    real_dst = dst
    if os.path.isdir(dst):
        if _samefile(src, dst):
            # We might be on a case insensitive filesystem,
            # perform the rename anyway.
            os.rename(src, dst)
            return

        real_dst = os.path.join(dst, _basename(src))
        if os.path.exists(real_dst):
            raise Error, "Destination path '%s' already exists" % real_dst
    try:
        os.rename(src, real_dst)
    except OSError:
        if os.path.isdir(src):
            if _destinsrc(src, dst):
                raise Error, "Cannot move a directory '%s' into itself '%s'." % (src, dst)
            copytree(src, real_dst, symlinks=True)
            rmtree(src)
        else:
            copy2(src, real_dst)
            os.unlink(src)
```

where `copytree`, `rmtree` and `copy2` are other public functions in the same module, and `_samefile`, `_basename` and `_destinsrc` are functions in the same module that are not meant to be part of the public API.

Python is not Java, after all; Java restricts you to one class per file, with the same name, and all code **must** be part of a class. In Python, classes are entirely optional.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the method using the class name as long as you provide the instance as the 1st argument (self). This will work for your class also.

Answer (score 0):

If your method can be called without a instance to work on then you can add the decorator `@static_method` to allow it to be called without an instance.  The python manuals covers this well.